# Casting DocumentSnapshot to CustomHashMap in Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document structure in one of my collections, basically, it keeps track of the social connection the user has. So I kept the document model as Custom HashMap only.
I customized the HashMap to add some methods to convert HashMap into some suitable data class.

Here is **Relation.java**

```
public class Relation extends HashMap<String,Object> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG="Relation.java";

    public ArrayList<String> getConnected()  {

        ArrayList<String> connected=new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> relation:this.entrySet()){

            Field status= null;
            try {
                status = relation.getClass().getField("status");
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int statusCode= 0;
            try {
                statusCode = Integer.parseInt((String) status.get(relation));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (statusCode==RelationState.CONNECTED){
                connected.add(relation.getKey());
            }
        }
        return connected;
    }   

}
```

Given below Is how the document would look like on the firestore, you may notice every FieldValue contains a map-like structure. So it is a kind of dynamic nested Map.
[image: documentsnapshot]

Now, whenever I try to convert the DocumentSnapshot to Relation object using

> *snapshot.toObject(Relation.class)*

The relation object is empty.

Thinks I have checked:

1. Logging snapshot obj prints all key-value pairs, hence snapshot is not empty
2. Everything other is working fine, take my word for it.

**The focus of question:**
How to cast DocumentSnapshot to custom HashMap in Firestore.

Comment: Show us the code that you are using and your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: There's no automatic casting from one to other, you have to translate them by coding, please update your question with the manual translation if you get any errors and a screenshot of your database structure